# passing tag id from php to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, variables, parameters

Hie:
i have managed to display multiple Divs using a foreach statement in php (the divs show different rows from a Database), and each of these Divs have a form at the bottom whose button evokes the javascript onclick function below.

```
 function SubmitForm(msg) {
var cid = $("#cid").val();
var message = $("#"+msg).val();

$.post(
"picturecomments.php", { cid: cid, message: message }, function(data)    
{alert(data);}
);
}
```

and below is the form

```
<form  action="picturecomments.php" method="post">
<span >
<input type="hidden" name="cid" id="cid" value="',$result['id'],'"required="required"/> 
 <textarea name="'.$message.'" id="'.$message.'" style="width:85%; height:25px;
 margin:0px;" placeholder="give a comment" required="required"></textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="SubmitForm('.$message.');"
id="searchForm"style="width:5%; height:25px; margin:0px;" value="Send"/>
</span>
</form>
```

my problem is when i try to click the send button, it always listens to the first div, 
so i have noticed that the problem is because i have just one ID FOR THESE TAGS AND WHEN THE SCRIPT RUNS, IT FINDS ONLY THE FIRST id...

how do i make the function run for multiple ids?
because when i have 2 divs, the function will only listen to the first form submit

the $message variable is within the same php code, i have done my research but i am failing to find a solution

PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: Do they all have the same id? An id is supposed to be unique.

Comment: Submit the id as well as the message to SubForm?  SubmitForm('.$result["id"].', '.$message.');

Comment: You should use classes instead, as they can be applied to more than one element. And then use jquerys each instead, as in Benjamin's answer

Comment: i have corrected my misunderstanding of the class and id uses... and used Benjamins Code... first as it is then with a few manipulations, the code, now loops through all the divs available but it says there is nothing in the textarea even if i type into all the divs

Answer (score 0):

you could use jquery each. assuming that you have multiple divs which have the class "post"

```
<div class="post">
  <input type="text" class="cid">
  <textarea class="msg"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="post">
  <input type="text" class="cid">
  <textarea class="msg"></textarea>
</div>


$( ".post" ).each(function( index ) {
    $.post( "picturecomments.php", { cid: $(this).find('cid').val(), message: $(this).find('textarea').val() }, function(data) {
       alert(data);
    });
});
```

So it will basically loop through all the divs that has the class post. Find a input field with class="cid" / class="msg" and then send it to your php processor.

Ofcourse this is pretty basic, but you'll work your way out of it!

http://api.jquery.com/each/

btw: make sure you dont use ID's. Their supposed to be unique!

Comment: Thanks, i have corrected the Class ? id issue.. but on clicking the send button, i get alerts equal to the number of Divs available.. saying that there is nothing in the text area... even if i type in all of them!

Comment: Jep, i noticed. I've edited the code. the message shoul be $(this).find('textarea').val() My bad, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use ID's at all, you can just use the names in each form and serialize it.

I would also remove the inline javascript (and css...) and the hard-coded `$message` as you will never be able to change the original message if you put it like that.

There is also no reason to use a different `name` attribute for the message in every form.

You also need to prevent the default / normal html form submit.

php / html

```
<form  action="picturecomments.php" method="post">
  <span >
    <input type="hidden" name="cid" value="' . htmlspecialchars($result['id']) . '" required="required"/> 
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="give a comment" required="required"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="Send"/>
  </span>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post(
    "picturecomments.php",
    $(this).serialize(),
    function(data) {
       alert(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: Nothing happens when  i click the Send button, iam assuming its failing to evoke the javascript code...

so i took the above code and put it in a named javascript Function which i then put as an onclick the buttons tag... but still nothing happens

Comment: @EmmanuelMatsiyana What version of jQuery are you using? jQuery's `on()` was added in ersion 1.7.